# PHP cURL send a POST request with authorization header field to an API

Tags: php, api, rest, oauth, php-curl

I'm a beginner in PHP and with working with API. I need to write a function in PHP which send a POST request to an API. In this request, I need to include an HTTP Authorization field with my username and Password. The API must send me back an OauthToken. While looking for solution, I understand that using cURL is well suited in this case but sadly, it doesn't work.

Here's my code :

```
$login = 'mylog';
$password = 'myPass';
$url = 'https://example.com/oauth/accessToken';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result == false)
    echo $ch;

curl_close($ch);  
echo($result);
```

Thanks for the help.

I expect a json file back and I got nothing instead. I would like to know what's missing from my code. thanks

Comment: Your example URL uses SSL yet the cURL code has no settings to negotiate SSL connections so it is likely there is an issue there or because no User-Agent is present the connection is being dropped. Analyse `curl_error` and `curl_getinfo` to find out more

Comment: It is my understanding that curl defaults to GET - you should provide this option to make a POST request: ‘curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);’

Answer (score 0):

I understand what's wrong with my code. I'm posting the solution here in case it can help someone in the future.

```
 $info = file_get_contents("./config/GenerateKeyInfo.json");
        $info = json_decode($info);
        $param =
        '{
            "grant_type" : "client_credentials"
        }';

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array(
            $curl, 
            [
                CURLOPT_URL => $info->endpoint,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_POST => true,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $param,
                CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$info->user:$info->password",
                CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type : application/json'),
            ]
        );
```

Since I'm a complete beginner in php and in web development. I didn't understand that my API was asking me to send it some kind of json file in my post request.